# Azure SQL DB not updating varchar length

Tags: sql, azure

I created a table using the following SQL command:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [my-azure-db].dbo.MyTable (
    Id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    Name nvarchar(32) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
);
```

When I check the table with DBeaver, it looks like this:
[image: DBeaver View]

Therefore, I tried to alter the table and change the size of the field with the following script.

```sql
ALTER TABLE [my-azure-db].dbo.MyTable ALTER COLUMN Name nvarchar(32) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL;
```

The script runs through and the varchar size is still stuck at 16. When I try to do this directly in the Azure Query Editor, it also does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
[image]

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable
(
    Id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    Name nvarchar(32) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
);

ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable ALTER COLUMN Name nvarchar(16) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Yes... That's exactly what I am doing. Is the length of the varchar really updated in your case?

Comment: Why use [my-azure-db].dbo.MyTable instead of dbo.MyTable. Try dbo.MyTable firstly.

Comment: Because I am working with multiple databases and need to define the corresponding DB. This is not the breaking point, since selects, inserts and updates work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced this in **Azure SQL Database**, and there is no change in the nvarchar size, and I am able to change it using query.

I created the above table with the name of **reprotable** and this is my table description with `nvarchar(32)`.

The code for table description below is taken from this [article](https://dataedo.com/kb/query/azure-sql/list-columns-names-in-specific-table) of **dataedo** by **Bart Gawrych**.

[image]

You can see the **max_length is 64** above which means it is `nvarchar(32)`.

Change to `nvarchar(16)` using your code.

[image]

Try to use `[dbo].[tablename]` and check the result as suggested by [Courser Xu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19538002/courser-xu).

And I suggest you try to create the table and Azure SQL DB and SSMS also if possible and check whether still you are getting the same.